# How do I set up scons to build a project that has generated source files?

Tags: c++, scons, generated

I'm working on a C++ project that has some hand coded source files, as well as some source and header files that are generated by a command line tool. 
The actual source and header files generated are determined by the contents of a JSON file that the tool reads, and so cannot be hardcoded into the scons script.
I would like to set up scons so that if I clean the project, then make it, it will know to run the command line tool to generate the generated source and header files as the first step, and then after that compile both my hand coded files and the generated source files and link them to make my binary.
Is this possible? I'm at a loss as to how to achieve this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Depending on which tool you're using to create the header/source files, you want to check our ToolIndex at https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsIndex , or read our guide https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools for writing your own Builder.
Based on your description you'll probably have to write your own Emitter, which parses the JSON input file and returns the filenames that will finally result from the call. Then, all you need to do is:

```
# creates foo.h/cpp and bar.h/cpp
env.YourBuilder('input.json') 

env.Program(Glob('*.cpp'))
```

The `Glob` will find the created files, even if they don't physically exist on the hard drive yet, and add them to the overall dependencies.
If you have further questions or problems arise, please consider subscribing to our User mailing list at scons-users@scons.org (see also http://scons.org/lists.html ).

Comment: It's my own custom tool that generates the source files. I could modify it to output a list of files that it's going to generate. Are you saying that I should create an Emitter for YourBuilder that calls my tool to return a list of output files, and then your example will work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example at:

https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/UsingCodeGenerators

I'll also echo Dirk's suggestion to join the users mailing list.

Comment: The link is not valid any more. And without following the link the answer doesn't contain any useful information: this is a direct sign of "**link-only**" answer. On Stack Overflow we avoid such kind of answers.

Comment: Updated link.  Would you rather I copied then entire content here?  The link points to information which is kept up to date (mostly)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dirk Baechle I got this working - for anyone else interested here is the code I used.

```
import subprocess

env = Environment( MSVC_USE_SCRIPT = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\VC\\bin\\vcvars32.bat")

def modify_targets(target, source, env):
    #Call the code generator to generate the list of file names that will be generated.
    subprocess.call(["d:/nk/temp/sconstest/codegenerator/CodeGenerator.exe", "-filelist"])
    #Read the file name list and add a target for each file.
    with open("GeneratedFileList.txt") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        content = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]
        for newTarget in content:
            target.append(newTarget)
    return target, source

bld = Builder(action = 'd:/nk/temp/sconstest/codegenerator/CodeGenerator.exe', emitter = modify_targets)
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'GenerateCode' : bld})

env.GenerateCode('input.txt')

# Main.exe depends on all the CPP files in the folder. Note that this
# will include the generated files, even though they may not currently
# exist in the folder.
env.Program('main.exe', Glob('*.cpp'))
```